# How can I remove Homebrew from Windows?

Tags: git, homebrew

I installed Homebrew on my Windows Git bash by mistake. I tried to fix it by re-installing Homebrew and tried to remove it. I even removed Git bash and re-installed it but that didn't work at all.

I'm new to this tool. May I ask for some advise to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to remove Homebrew or install it differently?

Comment: i'm try to remove it

Comment: What makes you think it's installed? Your screenshot doesn't show that.

Comment: ahh i think after i wrote /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)" this command that appear when i start git bash TT

Comment: can you add you `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file

Comment: i'm so sorry..... but i can't find where it is.... is it in program files\git folder?

Comment: Hey @SHH, I see you're on Windows, and might not have the .bashrc file (unless Git Bash adds it, I'm not sure). See if you can execute the following - `which brew`. If it prints a path, go to the path and delete the brew file.

Comment: @roshnet it doesn't prints a path.... it print just no brew in (blah blah)

Comment: Then i guess your goal is achieved

Comment: @roshnet no... that message stil "no such file or directory" shows up when i turn on git bash

Comment: go through this [link](https://github.com/Homebrew/install) to uninstall *homebrew*.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew supports Linux (formerly known as Linuxbrew). To uninstall it from Linux.

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

References

- [Homebrew (un)installer](https://github.com/Homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew)